# open data in new page from the link (index of array) in home page in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

In the first picture i have a table of data and i want to click on any link of any person(index) and opens the all data of this index (person) in new page like the pic 2 .

Here is my Picture 1 and picture 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you need to have a URL with the person ID, like this `app-url/persons/123`. After that, you need to get the ID in the component to fetch the data from the server. This way, each time you access the URL with the person ID, you will have your data. Finally, you can have a link that opens the page in a new tab, like this: `<a href="app-url/persons/123" target="_blank">Person name</a>` The `target="_blank"` on the a tag will open a new tab.